# assign points to a grid in r

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I have a (hopefully) straightforward task I need to accomplish, but so far I have not been able to find my answer in any of the existing threads.

Let’s say, I have a set of coordinates that correspond to the centers of cells of a 10x10 grid. Each grid cell has a unique identifier (a, b, c, d).

```
    x   y
a   5   5
b   5   15
c   5   25
d   5   35
e   15  5
f   15  15
```

(and so on)

I also have a set of coordinates “stations” that correspond to some spatial points laying somewhere on that grid

```
    x       y
A   7.5     12
B   33.2    21
C   12      16.6
```

(and so on)

I wish to create a table that would tell me which grid cell (a, b, c) each one of “stations” (A, B, C) belongs to.

Is there a (relatively) easy way to do this in R?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1jBm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicate data in question. If these exist as data.frames already you'll need to run the following for my code to work: `setDT(df)` `setDT(stations)` (Converts them to data.table class)

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("
grid    x   y
a   5   5
b   5   15
c   5   25
d   5   35
e   15  5
f   15  15
")

stations <- fread("
station    x       y
A   7.5     12
B   33.2    21
C   12      16.6
")
```

Make a data table with the bounds of each grid

```
bounds <- df[, .(xl = x - 5, xu = x + 5
                , yl = y - 5, yu = y + 5
                , grid )]
bounds
#    xl xu yl yu grid
# 1:  0 10  0 10    a
# 2:  0 10 10 20    b
# 3:  0 10 20 30    c
# 4:  0 10 30 40    d
# 5: 10 20  0 10    e
# 6: 10 20 10 20    f
```

Join `bounds` and `stations`

```
out <- bounds[stations, .(station, grid), 
                on = .(xl <= x, xu >= x,  yl <= y, yu >= y)]
out
#    station grid
# 1:       A    b
# 2:       B <NA>
# 3:       C    f
```